# CSS expression for "Not a Descendant Of"

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have this HTML

```css
.A {
  border: thick blue solid;
}

.B {
  border: medium red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="A">
    <div class="B">
      DON'T SELECT ME
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="B">
    SELECT ME
  </div>

  <div class="A">
    <div class="C">
      <div class="B">
        ALSO DON'T SELECT ME
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I, for example, set the background to yellow of the "SELECT ME" div, without doing so to the other two? I was thinking it should be something like:

```
.root>:not(.A) .B { background: yellow; }
```

... but that doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why; and searching the web isn't turning up anything to my shock and surprise. Is this something that can be achieved with CSS?

Comment: you would just need to style b and the add the override for b if it is a descendant of a

Answer (score 1):

```css
.A {
  border: thick blue solid;
}

.B {
  border: medium red solid;
}

.root > .B {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.A > .B {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="A">
    <div class="B">
      DON'T SELECT ME
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="B">
    SELECT ME
  </div>

  <div class="A">
    <div class="C">
      <div class="B">
        ALSO DON'T SELECT ME
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Targeting .B as a direct descendant of .root works:

```
.root>.B { background: yellow; }
```

Targeting .B as an direct descendant of .A would allow you to target the .A > .B selectors differently:

```
.A>.B { background: green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS nth-child rule. [more details here](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

```
.B:nth-child(2) {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```css
.A {
  border: thick blue solid;
}

.B {
  border: medium red solid;
}
.B:nth-child(2) {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="A">
    <div class="B">
      DON'T SELECT ME
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="B">
    SELECT ME
  </div>

  <div class="A">
    <div class="C">
      <div class="B">
        ALSO DON'T SELECT ME
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```